# How to remove these lines between Row children

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, and I'm trying to divide the screen into three parts, here's my attempt:

```dart
class Homepage extends Statelesswidget { 
  const HomePage({Key? key}): super (key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      const Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Text("Left")),
        ), // Scaffold
      ), // Expanded
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: const Center(child: Text("Middle")),
        ), // Scaffold
      ), // Expanded
      const Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Text("Right")),
        ), // Scaffold
      ) // Expanded
    ]);
  }
}
```

and main.dart looks like:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: result_image]

I got these vertical lines out of nowhere, how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Please provide a code here, not with image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Welcome to Flutter**

These lines are the boarders of the `Scaffold` widget which you are using inside each `Expanded` widget in the row.

**Now intead of looking for a way to remove these border lines, I suggest you to learn more about the `Scaffold` widget in Flutter**

Since you are new to Flutter, you have to be aware with the goal of using `Scaffold` widget, which is stated in the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) as the following:

> Implements the basic material design visual layout structure.
>
> This class provides APIs for showing drawers and bottom sheets.

So in other words, we use the `Scaffold` Widget as a basic canvas for the screen with some properties to implement popular layout designs, such as `AppBar`, `BottomNavigationBar`, `FloatingActionButton`, etc...

**Then, we use it once in the screen to set the basic layout, and does not required to be used multiple times for each sub part of the screen**

Then your `HomePage` code should be something like:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(children: [
        const Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Center(child: Text("Left")),
        ), // Expanded
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              AppBar(),
              const Expanded(
                child: Center(child: Text("Middle")),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Center(child: Text("Right")),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will make sure to read more through the widgets to know what to choose next time, however, with your approach I get three black spaces with the text in them, I have tried to place Containers to change the background color to white but I ended up with the same issue, could you suggest another way to do so?

Comment: Hmm, that's because I have forgot to wrap the whole screen with a `Scaffold` widget which makes the screen a basic layout canvas for your art. I have updated the code in the answer, check it again and if it works then I would be happy if you upvoted the answer and accepted it.

Comment: You're always welcome 